# Wordpress - Comprehensive Google Map

Tags: wordpress, google-maps-api-3

I am running wordpress 3.4.1 + plugin Comprehensive Google Map.
The plugins allows one to easily ad google maps + markers to any post or page.

**Question**

Is it possible to change the marker beheaviour to become a clickable URL. At present when you click on the marker it displays the marker information. I want it to go to a specified URL.

I am also open to using another plugin. All I really need is a google map with multiple markers that all have associated URL's attached, which I can embed into a page.

thanks in advance

Charles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the plugin that you are using but you can add some custom code to add extra functions to the marker. You should be able to locate in the plugin files this code:
"google.maps.event.addListener(marker,..." if you do then right after it you can add your own listener like this:

```
`google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() { window.location = "the desired url"; }`
```

when you check the plugins code it might already have a listener for the "click" event so you can edit that one without having to add another listener.